# How to disable click of a column from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on WindowsForm where I'm passing data from my database. The purpose of this `DataGridView` is to enable to user to click on a value and modify it. However, I don't want the user to leave the value blank, add words, only numbers.. and of course not change the Id, which is the primary key of my table.

I'm trying to achieve this by disabling the column which host the id of the table, however I don't know how to tell that column to disable editing.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class eraseGrade : Form
{
    Conexion con;
    String rut;
    DataTable dt;

    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    SqlCommandBuilder scb;

public eraseGrade()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cbxAsig.Enabled = false;
        cbxAsig.Enabled = false;
        btnNotas.Enabled = false;
        btnBorra.Enabled = false;
    }

private void btnBuscar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conexion con = Conexion.saberEstado();

        rut = txtRut.Text.Trim();

        if (validarTXTVacios(txtRut))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add a Rut, please");
        }
        else
        {
            Alumno a = new Alumno(rut);
            a.buscar(a);
            cbxAsig.Items.Clear();

            if (a.Nombre != null)
            {
                lblNombre.Text = a.Nombre + " " + a.Apellido;

                cbxAsig.Enabled = true;

                AsignaturaAlumno b = new AsignaturaAlumno();

                List<AsignaturaAlumno> l = b.buscarTodosByAlumno(rut);

                List<String> codigosAsig = new List<string>();

                if (l.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < l.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        codigosAsig.Add(l.ElementAt(i).Cod_asig.ToString());
                    }

                    Asignatura asigT = new Asignatura();
                    List<Asignatura> asig = new List<Asignatura>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < codigosAsig.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        asig.Add(asigT.buscarbyCod(codigosAsig.ElementAt(i).ToString()));
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < asig.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        cbxAsig.Items.Add(asig.ElementAt(i).CodAsignatura);
                    }

                    cbxAsig.Enabled = true;
                    btnNotas.Enabled = true;


                }

            }
            else
            {
                lblNombre.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Alumno no encontrado");
                lblAsig.Text = "";
                cbxAsig.Enabled = false;
                btnNotas.Enabled = false;
                btnBorra.Enabled = false;

            }

        }
    }

 private void cbxAsig_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conexion con = Conexion.saberEstado();

        Asignatura asignatura = new Asignatura();
        Asignatura l = asignatura.buscarbyCod(cbxAsig.SelectedItem.ToString());

        lblAsig.Text = l.Nombre + " (" + l.IdSeccion + ")";
    }
```

Here is the code that obtains data from the database and inserts it into the `DataGridView`.

```
private void btnNotas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conexion con = Conexion.saberEstado();

        if (cbxAsig.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            String codigo = cbxAsig.SelectedItem.ToString();

            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT id, num_eval AS Evaluacion, porcentaje AS Porcentaje, nota AS Nota  FROM registro WHERE rut = @rut AND cod_asig = @cod_asig", con.Con);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_asig", codigo);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            btnBorra.Enabled = true;
}
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seleccione una asignatura");
        }
    }

    public Boolean validarTXTVacios(TextBox r)
    {

        if (txtRut.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Here is the button that updates the table with the new data from the columns. It doesn't respect primary keys or data types.

```
    private void btnBorra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
         sda.Update(dt);


    }



}
}
```

Comment: Just set that column `ReadOnly` like this:`dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;` you should change `0` to the `id`'s column index.

Comment: That worked, but how could I validate the data type when editing?

Comment: Please do, yes. I understand using condition statements would be the way, but I'm not really familiar at how to handle datagrids.

Answer (score 2):

Just set that column's `ReadOnly` to `true` like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
```

You should change `0` to the `id`'s column index.

**EDIT**: To validate a column to be for example `int` you could do like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    int x;
    if (int.TryParse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out x))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but how about validating the data that is input by the user on any of the columns? Let's say I only want int on column[1]

Comment: @Midori_hige You could do more logic for validation user inputs. For example to make sure that user input is a valid int you can do this: `int x;
            if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() , out x))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Valid");
            }`

Comment: I'm getting a DataGrid Default Error Dialog saying FormatException whenever I input a letter into a cell,column where integers/int are suppose to be.

Comment: @Midori_hige I provided an example of how you could do validation for example *only int on column[1]*. See my updated answer.

Comment: It gets me a NullPointerException after popping up the valid message.

Comment: @Midori_hige Add this line before the `foreach` loop:      `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;`

Comment: It doesn't work for validating the data input. The DataGrid error message keeps showing up when typing a letter instead of a number.

Comment: It doesn't validate the column, nor the cell. The input data keeps showing up exceptions. I stated on my question that I wanted to disable a column and also to validate the input data on that column.

Comment: I don't need letters, symbols, blanks or anything other than numbers on any of my cells. That is.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting Row.Cells[cellIndex].Enabled = false; during GridView RowDataBound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Alter cellIndex to your actual id cell index.